# How to test for cents currency symbol in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to test for the cents currency symbol in my JavaScript program. I got the symbol into my file by doing this:

```
echo "\0242" > /tmp/cents
```

And then reading that file into my editor.

I have a variable with this value:

```
¢40.36
```

In my program I do this:

```
ax = (a[0][0] == '¢');
```

When my program run ax is False. But from the console it evaluates to True:

```
>>> a[0]
"¢40.36"
>>> ax
false
>>> a[0][0] == '¢'
true
>>> ax = (a[0][0] == '¢')
true
>>> ax
true
```

Can anyone explain this and tell me how I can test for the cents character?

Comment: How are you running the Javascript outside the console?

Comment: The code is in a .js file and it gets included in my page with <script src="myscript.js"></script>

Comment: It probably has to do with encoding. What browser are you on? If you placed the code in a JS Fiddle, is the problem still there?

Comment: Use `console.log(a, a[0][0], a[0][0]=='¢', ax)` after that line, and post the result here.

Comment: I was testing on Firefox. I'm not sure how to do a fiddle with just some js code. When I put the code into the js frame nothing happens when I run it. Do I have to have some html also?

Comment: @Oriol ["¢662.25", tr] ¢ true false

Comment: @LarryMartell Then I can't neither understand how `a[0][0] == '¢'` can be `true`, but `ax`, which is assigned to that, `false`. Can you post full code?

Comment: @Buck Doyle - it was an encoding issue - I saved my file as UFT-8 (by doing this in vim: :w ++enc=uft-8) and then it started working. Thanks!